# How do I create a list of atom pairs from two lists in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I am new to prolog.
Let me show you what I want below as  comment..

```
% ?-pair([1,2],[a,b],Result).
% Result= [{1,a},{1,b},{2,a},{2,b}].
```

and what I did is..

```
pair([],Q,[]).
pair(P,[],[]).
pair([A|P],[B|Q],[{A,B}|R]) :- pair([A|P],Q,R).
pair([A|P],[B|Q],[{A,B}|R]) :- pair(P,[B|Q],R).
```

with this code I reach such a result like this:

```
?- pair([1,2],[a,b],R).
R = [{1, a}, {1, b}] ;
R = [{1, a}, {1, b}, {2, b}] ;
R = [{1, a}, {1, b}, {2, b}] ;
R = [{1, a}, {2, a}, {2, b}] ;
R = [{1, a}, {2, a}, {2, b}] ;
R = [{1, a}, {2, a}] ;
false.
```

I want all in one line without repetitions..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by listing all the pairs A in L1 and B in L2 an collecting all pairs {A,B} in an other list:

```
pair(L1, L2, Pairs):-
  findall({A,B}, (member(A, L1), member(B, L2)), Pairs).

?-pair([1,2],[a,b],Result).
Result = [{1, a}, {1, b}, {2, a}, {2, b}].
```

Answer (score 5):

You should explain to Prolog what you want (what is a pair, how to build it), **then** ask Prolog to find all the pairs.